# Rerouting a Fault Path to the beginning of a flow

Tags: visual-workflow

What will happen if I route a fault path back to the beginning of a flow when a DML fails? Will the record keep looping to the beginning if the DML keeps failing?

Comment: of course - this is amenable to experimentation; I'd imagine you'll hit limits eventually

Comment: I thought after a pause element, a new transaction begins and this will reset limits right? Im thinking one way i can limit the number of loops is using an "ErrorCounter" variable. Is there other ways?

Comment: The community ethos is for the question poser to demonstrate effort and, if stuck, ask for help. This question veers on asking us to do your work for you. Do an experiment.

Comment: I see, thank you :)